# Vhdl error 10344 dont know what to do

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make set&load d-flip flop code(synch) but it keeps giving me `count <= '0' & d; it has 2 elements but must have 9 elements` error.Thanks in advance

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity syn is
 port (
 clk : in std_logic;
 rst_n : in std_logic;
 d : in std_logic;
 ld : in std_logic;
 q : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 co : out std_logic);
end syn;
architecture rtl of syn is
 signal count : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
begin
 co <= count(8);
 q <= count(7 downto 0);
 process (clk)
 begin
     if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
         if (rst_n = '0') then
             count <= (others => '0'); -- sync reset
         elsif (ld = '1') then
             count <= '0' & d; -- sync load
         else
             count <= count + 1; -- sync increment
         end if;
     end if;
 end process;
end rtl;
```

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong - quite accurately in this case.

Comment: An aggregate, e.g. `count <= (0 => d, others => '0');` wherein count(0) is assigned d and others (8 downto 1) are assigned '0'. Otherwise your intent is not clear. Are you intending to load only two index positions?

Answer (score 2):

Input d is std_logic, so `'0' & d` is 2 bit vector. Count is std_logic_vector of length 9, so you can't make assignment like this.
I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to assign '0' & d to some part of a vector, you can write for example

```
count(1 downto 0) <= '0' & d
```

If d is supposed to be equal size of counter, then change it's size in entity declaration.